# How to correctly set max_file_size for a file target of an extended event session?

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

I tried the following code to create an extended event session.

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION xetest
ON SERVER
    ADD EVENT rpc_completed
    ADD TARGET package0.event_file
    (SET filename = N'result.xel', max_file_size = (60), max_rollover_files = (5))
WITH (
    MAX_MEMORY = 512000KB,
    EVENT_RETENTION_MODE = ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,
    MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY = 30 SECONDS,
    MAX_EVENT_SIZE = 0KB,
    MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE = NONE,
    TRACK_CAUSALITY = OFF,
    STARTUP_STATE = OFF
);
```

However, I got below error messages when I run it.

```
Msg 25641, Level 16, State 0, Line 13
For target, "package0.event_file", the parameter "max_file_size" passed is invalid.
Target parameter at index 1 is invalid
```

I did some investigation and found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2016/ff878115(v=sql.130)):

> `max_file_size` must be larger than the current size of the session buffers. If it is not, the file target will fail to initialize, reporting that the `max_file_size` is invalid. To view the current size of the buffers, query the `buffer_size` column in the `sys.dm_xe_sessions` dynamic management view.

The problem is that `sys.dm_xe_sessions` *Returns information about server-scoped active extended events sessions*. Since the extended event session that I was trying to create hasn't exist yet. So I'm not able to query `sys.dm_xe_sessions` and get its `buffer_size` column. In this case, how can I know the correct minimum `max_file_size` value that can be used in the `CREATE EVENT SESSION` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in this line:

```
MAX_MEMORY = 512000KB
```

That's the buffer size for your extended event. As the error says, your `max_file_size` setting must be larger than this. Obviously, the number you used (60 MB) is not larger than the number you used for `MAX_MEMORY` (500 MB).

Also, as was mentioned in one of the comments, 500 MB is quite a large buffer size for an extended events session. You should normally need no more than 8 MB or even 16 MB at most.